# Memory allocation for primitive and reference variables

Tags: java

`type name;`

**For reference types,this notifies the compiler that you will use name to refer to data whose type is type. With a primitive variable,this declaration also reserves the proper amount of memory for the variable.**

Above are the exact lines i read from oracle docs java tutorials.

My question is, when does memory allocation take place. During compile time or run-time??
Is that same for both primitive and reference variables?

Comment: Any allocation takes place when your program runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Runtime.

As *Java* is executed by a `VM`, it does not make sense *allocating memory* at **compile** time.

'*Local variables*' like function *arguments* or variables *inside a function* are only '*allocated*' on the stack (primitive value or reference). Objects are *always* created on the **heap**.

**But:** everything concerning *memory management* (allocation, deallocation, garbage-collection) is `JVM` implementation dependent and happens *only* at **runtime** (except for *primitive* and *String constants* of course).

Comment: and literals.  Strings declared as " "  will go into permgen.

Comment: Everything constant will get into the Java Class File constant pool at compile time, and so into the permgen on class loading. (Everything that is either a constant String expression or anything that can be represented as a constant number value)

Comment: upboats for you sir, for a better explanation.

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout I like `upboats`, new word for the day ;)

Comment: What about static fields of the class.When doe's memory allocation take place @Neet

Comment: and yeah memory allocation during compile time is of no good and completely stupid.Sorry.May be static members are allocated just before program starts running.Not sure though

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation occurres in runtime and both reference types and primitives need allocation to be stored. To be more precise I can not understand what does it meant `memory allocation in compile time` (for `java`).